# Browse in? Surf in?

Tags: prepositions

Let's say your browsing an internet website. Then, you were having a hard time surfing the site coz the website's connection speed is slow(ex.The buffering time in Amazon's retail website is slow due to low quality of their modem. take note:the Amazon's website itself is the problem, not your browser, let's put it that way, maybe because of numerous consumers every second of the day). After that you emailed them coz' you're pissed off.

> ''Your website's buffering system winds me up, coz it is too slow, which makes it difficult to ***browse in*** your website.

Also:

> ''Your website's buffering system winds me up, coz it is too slow, which makes it difficult to ***surf on*** your website.

Are the **prepositions** in the sentences correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/browse), no preposition is required with browse when you **Scan through a text, website, or collection of data to gain an impression of the contents.** What you look at is the direct object of the verb.

The same applies for **surf**, but the meaning probably isn't quite right when you are talking about just one web site. The definition in the [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/surf) is **Move from site to site on (the Internet)**

Answer (score 1):

I would say that in the context of a website, **browse** is either intransitive

> I was on your site and **as I browsed**, this error message popped up...

or takes a direct object

> I **was browsing the site** when this error appeared...

Prepositions are marginal, to my ear, but **browse** is becoming synonymous with **navigate**:

> **Browse to** the Settings tab...

With **surf** there is greater variety:

> I was **surfing the web**...
>
> I fired up the browser and was **surfing around** ...
>
> I **surfed over to** that fact-checking website ...
>
> If visitors **surfed to** that link ...